# I keep getting "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException"?

Tags: java

I made a Java calculator, but when I enter a number that's really long, I get this error:
*Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "77777777777777777777777"
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2123)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at question1.Question1.main(Question1.java:26)*

Here's my coding:

```
package question1;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question1 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {int n1, n2;
    String operation;
    Scanner scannerObject = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter first number.");
    n1 = scannerObject.nextInt();

    Scanner op = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your operation.");
    operation = op.next();

    System.out.println("Please enter second number.");
    n2 = scannerObject.nextInt();

    switch (operation)  {
    case "+":
        System.out.println("Your result is " + (n1 + n2));
        break;

    case "-":
        System.out.println("Your result is " + (n1 - n2));
        break;

    case "/":
        System.out.println("Your result is " + (n1 / n2));
        break;

    case "*":
        System.out.println("Your result is " + (n1 * n2));
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Could not compute. Please only enter integers.");
   }
   }
   }
```

Thanks. :)

Comment: So *"77777777777777777777777"* is not a valid int and therefore your input doesn't match the scanners expectation. What is unclear about that?

Comment: The maximum value that can be stored in Java `int` is `2147483647`.

Comment: @Tom Would it have been too hard to just tell me if I can fix it? The "what is unclear about that?" was unnecessary.

Comment: @PM 77-1 Thank you for the information. My Java book did not ever tell me that.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextBigInteger()

Comment: Since `int` is too small, use type which can handle number that big. Depending on what numbers you are willing to accept you may want to use `nextLong()` or `nextBigInteger()`. About "My Java book did not ever tell me that" books are rarely only source of information. Java is quite well documented so be sure to read documentation of methods you are using like: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt-- which explains that `InputMismatchException` is thrown `if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range`.

Comment: @BoyGeorge *"Would it have been too hard to just tell me if I can fix it?"* No, but you neither asked for it, nor have you tried to search for that problem to find the solution by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The number `77777777777777777777777` (23 digits) is too long to fit in an `int`, because the [maximum `int` possible is about 2 billion (10 digits)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE).  It's also too long to fit in a [`long`, whose maximum value is 19 digits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE).

Either include an error message stating that the number is too big, or switch your datatype to `BigInteger`, by using [`Scanner`'s `nextBigInteger` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextBigInteger--).